# transfer color attribute

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

can I just ask u how may I fix the issue with a color attribute in the geo node?
What I need to get is a new attribute with the name col, which is based on the texture I am using (attribute sample texture). This attribute will be used as a value for the color of the points of the grid, which allows me to use it for coloring the instanced cubes, based on the color of the texture.
I would normally use the attribute transfer BUT since it's not possible in the new version of blender, I am a bit lost now.

May I kindly ask u guys for help? :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (*Blender 3.2*) you can solve this as follows:

[image]

1. Here you first use the node `Named Attribute` and get your *UVMap*. You use this as vector input for the node `Image Textute`. This will give you the color values.
2. The instantiation is done with `Instance on Points`.
3. To be able to use the desired attribute in the shader, you use the node `Store Named Attribute`.

After that you just select the material with the node `Set Material` (The material is not applied to the cube, but to the geometry you create here).

The most important part is `Realize Instances`, because even in *Blender 3.2* instances still can't handle values assigned to them, so they have to be converted to geometry first.